# Android Paging Library + Room relationships

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

The examples I've seen of the paging library all assume you need a `Livedata<List<T>>`, but how about Room relationships where the list is inside another object?

I have two entities in my app: `Conversation` and `Message` and they're related with this class:

```kotlin
data class ConversationWithMessages(
    @Embedded val conversation: Conversation,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "conversation_gid",
        entityColumn = "conversationId"
    )
    val messages: List<Message>
)
```

I never fetch all messages as a `LiveData<List<Message>>`, but a single conversation (by its ID) plus all its child messages. The DAO function looks like this:

```kotlin
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE conversation_gid =:conversationId LIMIT 1")
fun getConversationLiveDataById(conversationId: Long): LiveData<ConversationWithMessages>
```

I have a Repository which simply returns the `LiveData<ConversationWithMessages>` straight from the DAO.

In the Viewmodel, I have a `conversations` variable holding the livedata:

```kotlin
var conversation: LiveData<ConversationWithMessages> = MutableLiveData()
// ...
conversation = conversationRepository.getConversation(conversationId)
```

On my fragment, I just observe this livedata to update the adapter:

```kotlin
private val conversationObserver = Observer<ConversationWithMessages> {
    it?.let {
        // it.messages gives me the list I use to update
    }
}
```

**Initially I thought of using `PagedList` on the relationship data class:**

```kotlin
data class ConversationWithMessages(
    @Embedded val conversation: Conversation,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "conversation_gid",
        entityColumn = "conversationId"
    )
    val messages: PagedList<Message>
)
```

Then the DAO query which returns a `DataSource` would look like this:

```kotlin
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE conversation_gid =:conversationId LIMIT 1")
fun getConversationLiveDataById(conversationId: Long): DataSource.Factory<Int, ConversationWithMessages>
```

**But how do I transform this DataSource into a `LiveData<ConversationWithMessages>` where the child `PagedList<Message>` is configured?**
Google has this example, but I don't see how to apply it to this case:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface ConcertDao {
    // The Int type parameter tells Room to use a PositionalDataSource
    // object, with position-based loading under the hood.
    @Query("SELECT * FROM concerts ORDER BY date DESC")
    fun concertsByDate(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Concert>
}

class ConcertViewModel(concertDao: ConcertDao) : ViewModel() {
    val concertList: LiveData<PagedList<Concert>> =
            concertDao.concertsByDate().toLiveData(pageSize = 50)
}
```